# Frequent supply switching for a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

I want to create a LED chaser using pic12f683. The operation will be using a push button to turn on the uC.

Once the uC gets power it first of all incremennts a variable and writes it to the EEPROM. This variable defines from which point to start the sequence of the LED flashing program so that every power up it starts from a different point. I got 13 flashing modes in the program.

The uC will be on and keep flashing LEDs as long as the button is held.

I'm wrorried that the frequent and maybe very short pushes on the push button might damage the uC. Especially since the first thing it does is reading and writing to the EEPROM.

Ive implemented a 30ms delay before the read/write operation at start up as recommended. This is with the power up timer disabled.

Also I thought about putting a large capacitor in parallel to the battery supply so that VDD will fall a bit slowly.

How bad this design is to the uC?

Is it still really bad with my solutions?

What else should I do about it?

How to figure out a good value for the large capacitor if it is a decent solution?

Comment: Why do you think it would damage the uC? How do you have the button connected, if its connected on one side to ground and other to uC pin there's nothing to be worried about (that I know of).

Comment: except that he's using the switch in the power line to the uC...

Comment: @BrianDrummond Right. I missread that.

Comment: I made some assumptions in my answer such as battery type (AA), supply voltage (3.3), and that the LEDs are driven low by the microcontroller (anodes connected together to supply voltage). If any of these are incorrect let me know and I'll try to make modifications.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a small resistor in series with the Vcc to the MCU (maybe 10-100 ohms- chosen to drop perhaps 50-100mV in normal operation) and a capacitor in addition to the usual bypass capacitor of perhaps 100uF. You may need to add a bleeder resistor or a diode across the resistor to get the supply voltage to drop fast enough that a brief release of the pushbutton is recognized, depending on your circuit. This will help prevent any ESD from fingers on the switch destroying the micro. There is not really any other risk to the life of the micro from switching it on and off.

Functionally though, I would strongly suggest that you enable BOR and consider using an external supply supervisory chip (reset chip). This will help prevent EEPROM corruption. If you're not too concerned about the odd fault, the internal BOR is probably fine.

Answer (score 2):

This circuit should provide what you want.

[image]

You didn't say whether you are running off of 3.3V or 5V.  I assumed 3.3V but the circuit changes are minimal (two resistors).

I am also assuming you are using two AA batteries to drive the circuit.  Although you *could* run your microcontroller and LEDs directly off of the battery, the brightness of the LEDs would dim as your battery runs down.  Therefore I have included a boost switching regulator which keeps the supply voltage at a constant to 3.3V (or 5V).  Using a boost regulator should allow the individual batteries to drop down to 1.2V or even a little lower.

The circuit includes hardware debouching on the switch.  When the switch is closed, it enabled the P-channel MOSFET Q2, which in turns drives the battery boost regulator, which provides 3.3V to the rest of the circuit.  (If you need 5V, just remove R1 and R2).

When power is lost, the LEDs will no longer receive power, since they are behind the diode D2. Meanwhile the microcontroller will still be running since it is being powered by capacitor C2 for awhile; I'm guessing 100 ms or so.  I calculated that by treating the microcontroller as a 1100 Ω resistor (based on a 3.3V supply and 3 ma current) along with the 100 µF capacitor.

For the circuit to work properly, it is necessary to detect when power is going down. You should have one GPIO pin available, GP3, since it can only be used as an input. You don't need the \$\small \overline{\text{MCLR}}\$
functionality, since you are turning your entire circuit on and off.

With this pin you can monitor the Low Battery Output (LBO) of the regulator.  It will go low when the switch is released.  Since GP3 can perform an interrupt on change, you can use that to do any tidying up, and then go into a tight loop while the power goes completely down, meanwhile checking for the battery status.  If, in the unlikely case the power comes back up again while you are looping, you can just jump back to the beginning of your program.

In terms of writing to the EEPROM, waiting for a short period of time while the microcontroller starts up sounds like a good idea just in case the debounce circuit does smooth everything out all the time.  I would actually increase the time a little bit to 50 ms.  You should be okay writing to the EEPROM on power off, while being powered by the capacitor C2.  The EEPROM  on the PIC12F683 can be erased and re-written 1,000,000 times so you don't have to worry about endurance.

All parts are through-hole, making it easier to build.

Note: if you don't want to include the boost regulator circuitry, the circuit looks like this:

[image]

The functionality is the same, except you won't have a constant supply voltage.

Answer (score 0):

In some ways you are right. It wont damage your controller per se. But it will help to have a debouncing signal to filter out any false positives.

Your pressing the button might lead to small arcing which is never a good idea. The pin to which your push button is connected is ,ofcourse , an input pin. Unless you have a pull up or pull down (based on your input requirements) you could have spurious and dubious inputs that might disrupt the software execution.
3 things - provide a pull up resistor, give a low val cap to filter out nise (a Low pass filter) and finally implement a debouncing in software.

Finally, how many LEDs are you blinking. Is it done via a transistor or have you connected it directly to the uC pins. If latter, then its a bad idea.

Comment: I connect the LEDs directly to uC via current limiting resistors. The push button is a switch for the rail power not an input pin. I use all 5 available outputs on the uC

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is get out of power when writing to the eeprom, I think you can solve by:

1) You can implement 2 areas of data in the eeprom with checksum and serial number to store the data, for example Area A and Area B.

Read from areas and get the most recent data (using serial number) with a valid checksum.
Use and modify the data for your needs, increment the serial number and store in the oldest area (based in serial number) or in the corrupted area (based on checksum), the corrupted area have the priority.

Start your routine (the leds in this case) with the data.

If the writing is interrupted by power lost, you still have an area with good values.
The worst case is that your value is not incremented, but if you read/calculate/write before the leds routine, the user wont see the leds playing, so, It's like nothing happens.

2) The chip has 6 io pins, you can use the reset pin as input, you can put the switch in that pin to wake up the chip (I don't know if the pin can generate an interrupt nor wake up the micro).

3) You can power the chip all the time and enter in sleep mode, your switch can feed any pin with a resistor to wake up the chip and in your led routine, from time to time you change the direction of the pin to test if the voltage is still present (indicating the user still push the switch).

4) Using your capacitor approach, you can use a fet like the bs170 with a smaller capacitor value.